# JSON: JS parsing external JSON file (Can I drop the quotation markers?)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

```
{
    name: "Tesla",
    gender: "Male",
    info: {age: 88, interest: "Science"},
    x: 
    [
        {y: 1},{y: 2}

    ]

}
```

I use

```
var jsonData = eval("("+xmlhttp.responseText+")");
```

and this can parse the JSON file without `" "` around properties.

But for `JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)`

```
{
    "name": "Tesla",
    "gender": "Male",
    "info": {"age": 88, "interest": "Science"},
    "x": 
    [
        {"y": 1},{"y": 2}

    ]

}
```

JSON properties must be surrounded by `" "`.
Is there a way to do so without `" "`?

Comment: I guess, the question is why do you want to do that?

Comment: Also, there is no way to do that. You should play the game with rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way around it.

Without quotes around properties, it is not valid JSON.  You first example is a JavaScript object literal.

Answer (score 2):

By not having quotes around properties your JSON is not longer valid. Doing this is only going to cause you issues.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is a data format that is expressed as a **subset** of JavaScript.

The JSON specification requires that property names be expressed as strings (which must be quoted). JavaScript object literal syntax also gives the option of using identifiers.

`eval` can handle your property names as identifiers because that syntax is allowed in JavaScript, and `eval` evaluates code as JavaScript. `JSON.parse`, on the other hand, expects real JSON and that is what you must give it.

The quotes are required, keep them in.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` is evil. Check [this](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/) out for reading. However, you are using `JSON.parse` which requires newer version of your browser OR `json2.js` script.

But in my preference, I like to use how jQuery deserializes JSON to object using `new Function()`. Consider this code:

```
var jsonData = new Function('return ' + xmlhttp.responseText)();
```

This would work with and without "" :)